# Silverstripe sql debug

Tags: where-clause, sql-like, silverstripe, datamodel

How can I use `OR` with filter method e.g:

```
    $entries = BookstoreBook::get()
    ->filter(array(
    'Title:PartialMatch' => $searchString
    ));)
```

`Field:PartialMatch` is the way I found to use LIKE for string matching.

Comment: do you have a query example? You might be able to solve it by using an array with the field value...

Answer (score 2):

what about:

```
$entries = BookstoreBook::get()
  ->filter(array(
    'Title:PartialMatch' => array($searchString, $anotherString)
  ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FilterAny for OR:

```
$objects = $Object::get()->filterAny(array("Title"=>"Something","ID"=>"SomethingElse"));
```

You would also use a where if you HAD to:

```
$objects = $Object::get()->where("Title='Something' OR ID='SomethingElse'");
```

The relationship call also includes a where in the first parameter:

```
$objects = $Object::get("Title='Something' OR ID='SomethingElse'");
```

Any lastly, you can do a filter + a where, if you needed to, in some weird "I dont think youll ever find" situation:

```
$objects = $Object::get()->filter(array())->where();
```

;)